# Jquery callback function variables always local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Why cant i set the $('#temizle').innerHTML to string 'Temizlendi';
The code blow just doesnt work. But in the line before end i can set it. I'm confused.

```
        $('#temizle').click(function(){
            $.post('OdbcConnection.php',
                {islem: 'Temizle'},
                function(data, status){
                    if(status == 'success'){
                        alert(status);
                        $('#temizle').innerHTML = 'Temizlendi';
                    }else{
                        this.innerHTML = 'Hata Var';
                    }
                });
            //this.innerHTML = 'Temizlendi';
        });
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* this do?  Is there an error?  Specific unexpected behavior?  When you debug this, do the jQuery selectors find the element(s) you're looking for?

Comment: * There is no error. 
$('#temizle')   this is a <div> element.
* unexpected behavior is = I cant set its innerHTML property to the string 'temizlendi' on line #7.
* I cant set innerHTML property  to a string on line #9 either.
but;
I CAN set on line #12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is because `innerHTML` is a native DOM node method, not a jQuery method, therefore calling it on a jQuery object such as `$('#temizle')` does nothing but set a new `innerHTML` property in the jQuery object. It works outside of your `$.post` call because `this` inherits a native DOM node, not a jQuery object.

Try using the [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of `innerHTML`:

`$('#temizle').html('Temizlendi');`

Alternatively, outside of the scope of your `$.post` could also be re-written from `this.innerHTML` to `$(this).html()`, as wrapping `this` would convert it into a jQuery object.

If you absolutely have to use `innerHTML` rather than the jQuery method, as mentioned in other answers you can also get a DOM node from a jQuery object by using the `get()` method or accessing the node at the 0 index of the jQuery object:

```
$( '#temizle' ).get(0).innerHTML = 'Foo';
$( '#temizle' )[0].innerHTML = 'Bar';
```

Although that would sort of defeat the purpose of using jQuery.

Another thing to remember is that the value of `this` depends on the current scope, so `this` will not be equal to your element when it is called inside of your `$.post`. To get around this, you could cache your element outside of the scope of your post call so you can easily refer back to it within the callback:

```
$('#temizle').click(function(){
    var $el = $( this );

    $.post('OdbcConnection.php',
        {islem: 'Temizle'},
        function(data, status){
            if(status == 'success'){
                alert(status);
                $el.html( 'Temizlendi' );
            }else{
                $el.html( 'Hata Var' );
            }
        });

    //$el.html( 'Temizlendi' );
});
```

To get a better understanding of `this`, I'd highly recommend checking out the MDN reference on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: $('#temizle').html('Temizlendi');

That line solved the problem. Thanks to everyone. <3

Answer (score 0):

Is `alert(status)` getting called? If not this simply means your POST request failed.

If it indeed fails, check if the path to the php file is right. What you have now is a relative path, maybe you need to turn it to an absolute one,
ie.: change `'OdbcConnection.php'` to `'/OdbcConnection.php'` or `'/{SOME_FOLDER}/OdbcConnection.php'`

Comment: alert(status) works just fine. It alerts 'success'. But the property doesnt change.

Comment: Check the other answers, they nailed your problem which was confusing jQuery objects with native element objects.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to write

```
$('#temizle').html('Temizlendi')  //not   $('#temizle').innerHTML='Temizlendi'
```

or you can use

$('#temizle')[0].innerHTML ='Temizlendi'

second:you used

```
this.innerHTML = 'Hata Var';
```

but "this" is for function not for $('#temizle') element

Answer (score 0):

When you use **$('#temizle').InnerHTML**, you're calling the method **innerHTML**,  which belongs to DOM objects, but not the jQuery objects. In this case you should use the **html()** method of jQuery:
$('#temizle')html('Temizlendi');